# Subsetting data frame to include only one observation for average

Tags: r

I have the code below, and currently it prints out all 150 observations with the same output for the three different types of species. I am trying to get the set to just print out 3 rows, one for each type of species. Can anyone help me subset this?

```
iris_summary <- function(irisdata) {
           newiris = data.frame(irisdata$Species, 
                         MeanSepalLength = mean(irisdata$Sepal.Length), 
                         MeanSepalWidth = mean(irisdata$Sepal.Width),
                           MeanPetalLength = mean(irisdata$Petal.Length),
                           MeanPetalWidth = mean(irisdata$Petal.Width))
        return(newiris)
       }
iris_summary(iris)
```

Comment: The dimensions are being expanded by `irisdata$Species`, a long vector. There are many tools for summarizing frames including `dplyr::summarize` and `data.table`'s `x[,...,by=...]`. In base R, you should use something like `by` or `ave`, and there are many questions on SO that ask about or suggest those tools.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a homework problem and I am required to use a data frame. I am struggling to figure out the way to do it with the data frame, so was hoping to gain some assistance specific to data frames

Comment: Then try `unique(irisdata$Species)`

Comment: That helps me get the unique Species, right now I am still getting the same average for all species, is there an easy way to subset in a data frame to tell it I want each mean to be by species?

Comment: See `?aggregate`. e.g. `aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)`

Comment: Just got it using aggregate, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use dplyr summarise to get mean for all 3 species. Try this :

```
library(dplyr)
iris_avg <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean))

> iris_avg
# A tibble: 3 x 5
Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1 setosa             5.01        3.43         1.46       0.246
2 versicolor         5.94        2.77         4.26       1.33 
3 virginica          6.59        2.97         5.55       2.03
```